# List of 3D libraries based on WebGL

Tags: 3d, javascript, webgl

Is there a up-to-date list of WebGL libraries or articals with comparison? 
Until now I heard only three.js and GLGE.

Comment: It'd probably be a good idea to rename the title to "List of 3D libraries based on WebGL". It's not that huge for people looking at it now, it's easy to figure out what you mean, but when people will do searching for 3D engines for JS later they may not find this.

Comment: @dreta thanx man!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Khronos, the guys who are the "keepers" of OpenGL and WebGL have a preeeeeety loooooong list of WebGL stuff found on the web: http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/User_Contributions
And, the list is actively updated, although, there might be some outdated stuff hiding in-between.

And, I bet, that a little in depth browsing through http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page would give you more than enough information to get you started.

But, if you're looking for direct comparison chart, that's a problem. Because 3D graphics is such a broad term, and WebGL is nowhere near production use, all the libraries out there are basicly experiments.

There are no set guidelines what a WebGL library should boast, therefore, it's hard to compare them.

Comment: The WebGL list on Khronos is an open community wiki (http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Main_Page). If you do find anything missing, or out of date in your search for content, you are encouraged to make updates.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into this question, and creating a comparison of my own. As a starter I used this post.

http://weblog.benjaminsommer.com/blog/2012/05/13/comparison-of-webgl-framework-apis/

While this is not a comparison of the complete list of WebGL frameworks, it is more then I have found available. If anyone else has similar links I hope they share!

Answer (score 1):

My own super-lightweight [barebones.js](https://github.com/williame/barebones.js) can do basic matrix and vector math, load and draw fonts, textures and animated meshes.  It has a super-basic 2D UI framework too.

I actually have quite a lot of stuff I made for my last [Ludum Dare entry](http://williame.github.com/ludum_dare_24_evolution/) - a 3D online multiplayer space combat game - to fold back into barebones.js including performance improvements, fps counters and so on.

Finally I've got some newer mesh collision code, auto-normals code and other goodies under development for my latest hobby game; I'll fold them into barebones.js when they work too.

All in all its super lightweight and is super-easy to initialise your canvas properly, give you simple glu equivs like look-at, unproject, perspective etc as well as quaternions and that kind of stuff.  And then it gets out of your way and lets you make your game!

I'd be happy to fix and improve if others use it too.  Long live hobby coding!